# Missing Permission required by connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo.android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

Tags: java, firebase, kotlin, webview, uiwebview

I tried I to invalidate and restart caches but the problem still exists, here is a code of AndroidManifest.xml
I am using Android studio version 4, and When I try to run my APP I receve the message that :Error,Default Activity not found, please help me how I can solve this problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.megatechnologyteam.megavidi">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Below is where an error occur from MainActivity

```
public void checkConnection(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo wifi = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        NetworkInfo mobileNetwork = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if(wifi.isConnected()){

            webView.loadUrl(webUrl);
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }else if(mobileNetwork.isConnected()){

            webView.loadUrl(webUrl);
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }else{
            webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }
```

What is a problem and how can I solve this

Comment: So what is the error "Default Activity not found" or "Missing Permission"?

Comment: Default Activity not found is the error which I get

Answer (score 0):

If the error you get is `Default Activity not found` it means that your `AndroidManifest.xml` has incorrect setup.

Things to do:

1. Make sure `SplashActivity` and `MainActivity` exist;
2. Specify full package name to your Activities. Instead of `android:name=".MainActivity"` it can be for example `android:name="com.app.package.MainActivity"`;
3. Try next configuration for your manifest if `SplashActivity` does not exist:

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
```

If your manifest's setup is correct and you are sure Activities exist then try invalidating caches and restart the Android Studio:

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
```

Or double press the shift button and enter `invalidate caches` and select the first option.